# Best way to build url and setup Route53 to route traffic to the backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, web-applications, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

Currently I have R53 pointing my www. domain to a CloudFront dist which points to an S3 bucket which contains my frontend html, css, js etc..

This works great.

Now I'm adding a "contact us" form to the site. I intend to build an API Gateway which then calls a Lambda function to deal with the submit.

What's the best way to form the URL so that R53 directs the request to API Gateway instead of CloudFront?

Presumably a sub domain would work? Is that the norm? Is there a naming convention most people follow?

Something like `https://api.mydomain.com/contactus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a misconception of what Route53 does. Route53 is a DNS-Service, it routes traffic to Servers/Hosts via their IP-Address and doesn't know about Paths in your URLs (except when you use them in Health Checks) - Route53 deals with OSI-Layer 3, while Paths are Layer 5 and above.

If you want Path-based request-routing you'd have to use an Application Load Balancer with S3 and Lambda as Targets for your routes ([Lambda support for this has recently been announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/alb-can-now-invoke-lambda-functions-to-serve-https-requests/?nc1=h_ls)) - unfortunately S3 is [not a supported target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html?shortFooter=true#target-type) here.

The best solution would probably be to implement the form in your static website and then use Javascript to submit it to your API-Gateway endpoint, but you have to make sure CORS is enabled on the API Gateway.

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution at the end is the same as my subdomain suggestion. I'll implement that. Cheers.